# Unable to print from a DB using <logic:iterate> and <logic:bean>

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, struts-1

I am working on a small Struts 1.2.4 Phonebook app. 
The app contains forms in a single JSP to add , search , and edit/delete the data. My problem lies in displaying the ResultSet which is Obtained on performing a wildcard search. Here's the flow of the program :

1. User enters a search string.
2. Request is passed to a DispatchAction class's search() method , which in turn calls a searchContact(String name , HttpServletRequest request) method of a 'model' class.
3. The method executes SELECT query on the DB using a PreparedStatement, which returns a resultset, the values of which are put in an ArrayList< PhoneBook >. The class PhoneBook is a JavaBean with two fields, 'c_name' and 'p_num' , with getters and setters.
4. logic:bean and logic:iterate tags are used to print the contents of the ArrayList< PhoneBook > in the JSP.

**In the JSP :**

```
    <html:form action="/PhoneBookAction.do" method="post"  >

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><html:text property="name"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <html:submit property="method" value="Search"/>

        <br><br><br>

        <table align="center" border="2" bordercolor="royal blue">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><b> Select </b></td>
                    <td><b> Name </b></td>
                    <td><b> Phone Number </b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <logic:iterate id="search_resId" name="phonebookform" property="search_res">
                <tr>
                    <td> <bean:write name="search_resId" property="c_name" /> </td>
                    <td> <bean:write name="search_resId" property="p_num" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </logic:iterate>
        </table>

    </html:form>
```

This usually gives a "Bean not found in any scope" error, or prints nothing. I tried the fixes suggested in some similar threads, But none of them seem to work. Looking forward to a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding "type" attribute in your iterate statement. I'm guessing it's a string. <logic:iterate id="search_resId" name="phonebookform" property="search_res" type="java.lang.String">. If this doesn't work, show us your struts-config file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Susie!                          **"search_res"** is an ArrayList of PhoneBook objects and is declared , with getters and setters in PhoneBookForm.              The PhoneBook class contains two fields : 'c_name' and 'p_num' , which correspond to the fields in the database.                                                       I will try the fix you suggested , and update the question.

Comment: @Susie hi, I tried that, but it is not working. Is the way I have set up my objects, and the way they interact not Ideal as per the struts framework?